# Instagram API: force prompt during authentication

Tags: api, oauth, instagram

Is there a way for the instagram auth(login) to always ask for authentication? This is skipped when the user is logged in and has already authorized the app.

It would be something like twitter's `use_authorize=true` or google's `approval_prompt=force`.

Comment: Did you find how to force it ?

Comment: @PlumillonForge No as well. Have you? I just left it like that for now...

Comment: I have actually done it ! For Android answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378345/switch-user-or-re-authenticate-with-instagram But you can adapt this to whatever you want, the point is to delete the Instagram cookie sessionid from your browser

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the most simple way is to use next url:

```
https://instagram.com/accounts/logoutin/?force_classic_login=&next=URLENCODED_INSTAGRAM_OAUTH_URI_PATH_WITH_YOUR_DATA
```

For example:

```
window.location.assign('https://instagram.com/accounts/logoutin/?force_classic_login=&next=' + encodeURIComponent('/oauth/authorize/?response_type=code&scope=public_content+follower_list+comments&client_id='+ YOUR_IG_CLIENT_ID + '&redirect_uri='+encodeURIComponent(YOUR_REDIRECT_URI)));
```

Please take a note that your redirect uri should be encoded twice

Comment: What was the URL you're using?  I feel like that has something to do with it, as I'm guessing instagram is going to sanitize the "next" parameter

Comment: something like this:
https://instagram.com/accounts/logoutin/?force_classic_login=&next=%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%2F%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dpublic_content%2Bfollower_list%2Bcomments%26client_id%3D00000000000000000000000000000000%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fa%252Fa%253Ft%253Dig%2526u%253D0%2526g%253D0

(domain and client id are not real here)

Comment: Hmm... that's weird.  That's what I'm using, but it's not forcing the login.  Thanks for the responses :-)

Comment: Yeah, this works and is the right answer IMO. The `next` parameter needs to be a relative URL within the Instagram web app so `/oauth/authorize...` is fine, but `https://mywebapp/auth` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working:

I try loading an image with the url of the instagram logout page before opening the authorize popup.
Something like this (coffeescript):

```
windowOpen = ->
    window.open("/instagram/authorize?...")

if forceLogin
    tryLogout().always ->
        windowOpen()
```

And the tryLogout function (setTimeout 10seconds as a fallback)

```
tryLogout: ->
    deferred = $.Deferred()
    logOutImg = new Image()

    logOutImg.onerror = ->
        deferred.resolve()
    logOutImg.onload = ->
        deferred.resolve()

    logOutImg.src = 'https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/'

    setTimeout(->
        deferred.reject()
    , 10000)

    return deferred.promise()
```

Comment: This is not... a "reasonable" solution.  You don't want to log people out of their instagram accounts, just reconfirm that they want to associate a service with that particular instagram account.

Comment: @mpowered then i didn't understand the question

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution : you have to delete the Instagram cookie named `sessionid` from your browser so Instagram doesn't recognize you anymore

Solution for Android is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26847187/328845

Comment: The cookie is on the "instagram.com" domain so it's not possible to delete it from a web app on an alternative domain. :-/