# Is there a way to force an Authorization Request on Instagram OAuth requests?

Tags: oauth, instagram

If a users authorizes my app with Instagram, then log back in, my callback is immediately called. If a user wishes to change their account, they can't without logging out of instagram.com first.

Basically, I'd like to force the user to see this interstitial every time they login:

[image: Authorization Request Screen]

Comment: I'm not immediately familiar with Instagram's setup, but I strongly doubt that this is possible, since in the vast majority of cases it would be nothing more than a frustration to users. I assume you'd know if there were some way to disassociate (or log out, maybe?) users on your side. Why are you looking for this functionality?

Comment: The hootsuite instagram app seems to behave that way, so there must be some way.

Comment: @iMack would you please show the part of code you are authenticating the user at ?

Comment: @iMack Why would you want that behavior?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right UX but this should help? http://instagram.com/developer/restrict-api-requests/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was partially answered here: [Instagram API: force prompt during authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550048/instagram-api-force-prompt-during-authentication)

The answer by Plumillon Forge says:

> Here is the solution : you have to delete the Instagram cookie named
>   sessionid from your browser so Instagram doesn't recognize you anymore

...BUT the question is how to reset the sessionid cookie for a web user, since it's on the instagram.com domain.